# Javascript loads offline but not in drupal

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I am trying to incorporate the Javascript and load it into drupal. The problem is executing it. I know it is a simple problem but my knowledge does not extend beyond adding the javascript to the drupal page. When I load it in dreamweaver offline it loads perfectly and works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//function for contact form dropdown
function contact() {
    if ($("#contactForm").is(":hidden")){
        $("#contactForm").slideDown("slow");
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({"opacity": "0.7"});
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
```

I know the problem is with the first three lines. Cause when I load it in chrome it tells me the problem is on line 1.

I know it is something with drupal, I don't know if javascript needs to be loaded differently in Drupal.

The error that is given is: UnCaught Type Error : Property $ of Object Window is not a function.

Assistance for ignorance please....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//function for contact form dropdown
function contact() {
    if ($("#contactForm").is(":hidden")){
        $("#contactForm").slideDown("slow");
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({"opacity": "0.7"});
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow"); 
    }
    else{
        $("#contactForm").slideUp("slow");
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");  
    }
}

//run contact form when any contact link is clicked
$(".contact").click(function(){contact()});

//animation for same page links #
$('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : false;
        if ($(this.hash).length) {
            $(this).click(function(event) {
                var targetOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top;
                var target = this.hash;
                event.preventDefault();            
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 500);
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
});



  //submission scripts
 $('.contactForm').submit( function(){
    //statements to validate the form   
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    var email = document.getElementById('e-mail');
    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
        $('.email-missing').show();
    } else {$('.email-missing').hide();}
    if (document.cform.name.value == "") {
        $('.name-missing').show();
    } else {$('.name-missing').hide();} 
    if (document.cform.message.value == "") {
        $('.message-missing').show();
    } else {$('.message-missing').hide();}      
    if ((document.cform.name.value == "") || (!filter.test(email.value)) || (document.cform.message.value == "")){
        return false;
    } 

    if ((document.cform.name.value != "") && (filter.test(email.value)) && (document.cform.message.value != "")) {
        //hide the form
        $('.contactForm').hide();

        //show the loading bar
        $('.loader').append($('.bar'));
        $('.bar').css({display:'block'});

        //send the ajax request
        $.post('mail.php',{name:$('#name').val(),
                          email:$('#e-mail').val(),
                          message:$('#message').val()},

        //return the data
        function(data){
          //hide the graphic
          $('.bar').css({display:'none'});
          $('.loader').append(data);
        });

        //waits 2000, then closes the form and fades out
        setTimeout('$("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");      $("#contactForm").slideUp("slow")', 2000);

        //stay on the page
        return false;
    } 
  });
//only need force for IE6  
$("#backgroundPopup").css({  
    "height": document.documentElement.clientHeight 
});  
});
```

Comment: Are you remembering to include jQuery?

Comment: I added Jquery tags. I read somewhere on stackoverflow that the slide effect might be a jquery ui instead of jquery. Problem is this comes from an example I saw on the web, and it uses jquery-1.3.2 and I dont know if jquery is backward compatible and if these functions still work, cause I use Drupal 7.

Comment: So I tried to add the jquery to the page I am loading it into, but obviously Drupal 7 loads it own jquery into every page and I think the two are conflicting, I was hoping to just use the newer one. Cause it breaks the page when I aad the jquery.1.3.2 and I dont even think that is a good idea. So I am lost. When I had the jquery tags it says I have an error on line 16. But that means nothing to me as I have no idea about jquery and javascript. Just trying to learn.

Comment: Clive's answer works. Played around with it a bit more and got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` isn't an alias for `jQuery` by default in Drupal 7, you need to pass it in like so:

```
(function($) {
  // Your code here
})(jQuery);
```

See [Managing JavaScript in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/756722) for more info.

Comment: I tried getting it to work, but it doesn't even with Jquery tags.

Comment: Can you make this work for me please? :( <-- sad face shows desperation.